# Android RecyclerView shows multiple items at same position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having a number of weird things happen in my RecyclerView class that I believe are all connected. First, here is my implementation:

**onCreateViewHolder**

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    padding = parent.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.rec_padding);

    switch (viewType) {

        case USER:

            View userView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_view, parent, false);
            return new UserViewHolder(userView);

        case POST:

            View postView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_view, parent, false);
            return new PostViewHolder(postView);

        default:

            return null;
    }
}
```

**onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

        case USER:

            UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
            User user = (User) items.get(position);

            if (position == 0) {

                userViewHolder.recCard.setPadding(0, padding, 0, 0);
            }

            //Get relevant date for user

            if (user.getExpanded()) {

                userViewHolder.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            userViewHolder.showDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (userViewHolder.details.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {

                        userViewHolder.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        user.setExpanded(true);
                    } else {

                        userViewHolder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        user.setExpanded(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            break;

        case POST:

            PostViewHolder postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder) holder;
            Post post = (Post) items.get(position);

            if (position == 0) {

                postViewHolder.recCard.setPadding(0, padding, 0, 0);
            }

            //Get relevant date for post

            break;
    }
}
```

So the problems I'm having:

1) I am adding padding to the top of only the first item in the list. This is working as expected for the first item. However, once I start scrolling the padding is eventually added to the top of other items in the list. My assumption is that once I reach a certain point in the list of items, a new item is at position 0, so it also gets the extra padding.

2) I am trying to save certain properties about each item in the RecyclerView, particularly whether they are expanded or not. I am doing that by storing their expanded state as a boolean in the object itself and then retrieving it within `onBindViewHolder`. This isn't working though—similar to above, other items in the list are also showing up as expanded once I scroll. So the expanded state isn't be preserved properly.

Comment: This is a bit confusing but perhaps you might be able to clean it up a bit by moving all that logic out of your recycler adapter into a recyclerview decorator by recyclerView.addItemDecorator(). This is a much better approach for i.e. adding paddings

Comment: @mhenryk what part is confusing (so that I can make it clearer)? As far as using a decorator though, I think it will end up making it more complicated. At the moment there are three lines of code to check if the extra padding should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem:

> 1) I am adding padding to the top of only the first item in the list.
>   This is working as expected for the first item. However, once I start
>   scrolling the padding is eventually added to the top of other items in
>   the list. My assumption is that once I reach a certain point in the
>   list of items, a new item is at position 0, so it also gets the extra
>   padding.

The view that appears for 0-th item is recycled once you start scrolling. You need to reset it's padding to original state somehow. Quick and easy way would be to add something like this to your onBindViewHolder:

```
if (position == 0) {
  userViewHolder.recCard.setPadding(0, padding, 0, 0);
} else {
  userViewHolder.recCard.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

A better and more appropriate way would be to use ItemDecoration as mentioned in the comments above. It's not too complicated and probably make your code cleaner.

For your second problem:

> 2) I am trying to save certain properties about each item in the
>   RecyclerView, particularly whether they are expanded or not. I am
>   doing that by storing their expanded state as a boolean in the object
>   itself and then retrieving it within onBindViewHolder. This isn't
>   working though—similar to above, other items in the list are also
>   showing up as expanded once I scroll. So the expanded state isn't be
>   preserved properly.

Similarly to the first problem, your expanded views are recycled and whoever picked them up never restores the view state into not-expanded. You could add something like this:

```
if (user.getExpanded()) {
  userViewHolder.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
  // do whatever to restore view state into non-expanded
  userViewHolder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, that's one of those ones that I feel stupid for not noticing before... Thanks for the help, it's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove your all padding codes from your adapter. [ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) is what you looking for.

Secondly, set your onclick in UserHolder so you will have only one instance for all user views.

Other users posts are also expanded because you did not write else state where you hide details. There is a reason why this component called recyclerview. You create once and using same view more and more. So each time it's being recycled (where it's need to be shown) onbind method is called. And it's being drawn by previous state..

Answer is yes, all these bugs relies on same mistake. From Java Best Practices; Every if state should have an else state.

PS: This is optional but I would use recyclerview inside recyclerview for implementing posts for and expanded user view. You can change visibility of inner recyclerview that used for populating posts (Maybe you did since I didnt see your holder classes)

Good luck there

Emre

Comment: Thanks it's working now! And the posts are a separate kind of card displayed within the RecyclerView, along with the users. They aren't content that shows up within expanded user views. Thanks for the suggestion though.